# Ez Publish Unable to get REST API working

Tags: rest, ezpublish

I am new to Ez Publish, I would like to make the default Rest API working as a first step and next developing my own Rest API extension for mobile communication purpose but I am blocked at the first one.

when I try to get the result from **"www.mydomain.com/api/ezp/content/node/2/list"** I get **"{"error_message":"Not Found"}"**

configurations are done:

**setting/override/site.ini.append.php**

```
[ExtensionSettings]
ActiveExtensions[]
ActiveExtensions[]=ezprestapiprovider
...
```

**extension/ezprestapiprovider/settings/rest.ini.append.php**

```
<?php /* #?ini charset="utf-8"?

[ApiProvider]
ProviderClass[ezp]=ezpRestApiProvider

[Authentication]
RequireAuthentication=disabled

*/ ?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule api index_rest.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index_rest\.php - [L]
...
```

I apologize for my English.

**Edit1: Ez Publish version 4.5**

**Edit2:** It seems to be a problem of RewirteRule, when I change **"www.mydomain.com/api/ezp/content/node/2/list"** to **"www.mydomain.com/index_rest.php/api/ezp/content/node/2/list"** it works , how can I fix that ?

**Edit3:**
I tried all rewriterules below, still not working except the last one.

```
# RewriteRule ^/api/ /index_rest.php [L] 
# RewriteRule ^api/(.*) /index_rest.php/$1 [R=302,NC] 
# RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) /index_rest.php/api/$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule api index_rest.php [L]
```

But it seems to create conflit when I try to add new extension...
I added a new extension and when I try to access to it I got an error on the log file:

**Unexpected error, the message was : The API provider 'mobile' could not be found. in mydomaine.com\kernel\private\rest\classes\rest_provider.php on line 37**

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing those rewriterules with the one specified by eZ

```
RewriteRule ^/api/ /index_rest\.php [L]
```

This is listed here for version 4.5: http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.5/Installation/Virtual-host-setup

Comment: I tried all rewriterules below, still not working except the last one.
    # RewriteRule ^/api/ /index_rest.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^api/(.*) /index_rest.php/$1 [R=302,NC]
    # RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) /index_rest.php/api/$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule api index_rest.php [L]

But it seems to create conflit when I try to add new extension...

Answer (score 1):

I just regenerate autoload and it's working now. I use cmd line to do it (regenerating autoload with admin module does not work for me).